# Paste more than 4k worth of data into textarea from a Cucumber step (using Capybara)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I have a text area in a form that accepts JSON-formatted data to create a set of objects. I've written the step for that part as:

```
Then /^I should be able to paste JSON\-formatted data to create a new set of objects$/ do
  json_data = JSON.parse(File.read(Rails.root.join("features", "support", "example.json")))
  fill_in 'survey', :with => json_data
  click_button 'Create'
  # ...
end
```

When I run the feature however, it keeps failing with the error `ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow`. I've discovered from reading up in that error that it generally is triggered when more than 4k worth of data is stored in a cookie-based session, which leads me to believe that Cucumber/Rails is transferring the data-to-paste to a cookie that Capybara can then pick up and use in the form.

Is there a way that I can tell webrat to paste this data in smaller chunks? Or, is there another way of getting a large amount of data into a textarea during a test? The size of the example file is 37k.

Comment: Are you sure you're not putting the data in a cookie or in the session somewhere (are you storing any of the created objects in the session). I've never heard of capybara or webrat doing anything like what you are describing

Comment: I'm not setting any cookies explicitly, and the step is exactly as shown above. If I truncate the example.json file to be less than 4k, then it works fine.

Comment: How about showing some of the controller code?

Comment: I can paste the controller code when I get to my desk, but this problem is only present while running the test and only on the step that attempts to paste the JSON data. I can paste at least 37k worth of data (the most I've ever needed to try so far) in the live application without error.

Comment: On a sidenote: 'survey' is a textarea, right? Any reason why you put **parsed** JSON (i.e. a Ruby hash) in there instead of just `fill_in 'survey', :with => File.read(...)`?